# How to create a value typed Struct with strings?

Tags: c#, string, struct, value-type, reference-type

I want to read a MemoryMappedFile with a struct. Strings are located in this file. So I created a struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MemMappedFile
{
    
    [...]
    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
    public string SomeString;

    [...]
}
```

I get the error

```
System.ArgumentException: The specified Type must be a struct containing no references.
```

From my understanding the string is a reference type but the marshaling should manage this, but it doesn't - probably I am using it wrong.

How can I use a string in a struct, which needs to be out of value types only?

Comment: How are you using the struct?

Comment: From what I've read in related questions here on SO, the canonical solution seems to be to use an appropriately sized `byte[]` instead and encode/decode your strings with Encoding.GetBytes/GetString.

Comment: Use byte array to represent the string.

Comment: I need to use an unsafe context for that, I guess?

Comment: @SohaibJundi The Struct is used to read a MemoryMappedFile with a MemoryMappedViewAccessor. Therefore it needs to know the correct size of the struct and that throws the error.

Comment: @Heinzi can you write your comment as answer, so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0):

The string itself is not stored in the struct. Instead a reference to the string is stored in the struct, so the struct size never changes.

**string** is not a value type; .NET strings are interned, which means that each unique string is stored in a look-up table in memory.

Comment: I know, that's what I wrote in the question under the code. I understood the MarshalAs Attribute as a workaround for it, because the problem is not the reference but the fact, that it's not possible to get the sizeof the struct when it uses a reference type in it.

Answer (score 0):

@Heinzi's answer was correct.

I had to use byte[] and use an unsafe context.

Comment: You do not have to write which answer helped. Instead vote the correct answer up and mark the answer as correct.
I know that it was not possible to mark the answer as correct since the answer was only a comment in this case. I suggest to ask the original author to write his anser into a answer, which you can mark as correct.

Comment: thanks for your help